# Autoit ControlClick not working with java application

Tags: java, autoit

Im trying the test my Java app
I created a jar file and I was able to run it with AutoIt3.

Im trying to use the ControlClick functions but it doesnt work.
I think its because the control info is empty (when using Au3Info the control tab is empty)
This is the code:

```
$hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]","",10)
ControlFocus ($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]")
ControlClick($hWnd,"","[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]", "left", 1, 120, 100)
```

I tried with or without the ControlFocus but without succsess
I even tried only:

```
ControlClick("[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]","","[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]", "left", 1, 120, 100)
```

or

```
ControlClick("[CLASS:SunAwtFrame]","","", "left", 1, 120, 100)
```

MouseClick works but I want to able to run the script even if windows is on logging screen
(https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_my_script_work_on_a_locked_workstation.3F you can see here what u need to do to enable it, the function you can and cannot use.)

Comment: Have a look at the IUIAutomation framework - http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/

Comment: If don't want to wade through that framework, have a look at `WinGetPos` and `ControlGetPos`.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove I dont see how this is helping me? lets say I have the the size and postion of the control. what now? I still cant use controlClick, I dont have any information about it

Comment: Yes, you do. You have the size and position. Unless you use the IUIAutomation framework, then yes the size and position will be the only information you will get. I've done scripts with this exact way, so I know its possible :) have a try, and post your results in the original post.